# My notes on $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$-theoretic computational complexity

Tags: computer-science, finite-fields, computational-complexity, formal-languages

*(Question at the very bottom)*

**Def 1.** Let $F = \Bbb{Z}_p$ be a finite field.  Then an ***$F^k$-machine*** is a machine with $k$ input / output memory slots.  All computations are done in the field $F$ and in a problem-specific amount of arithmetic registers.  Thus algorithms on a  $F^k$-machine can be specified with a set $\{P_1, \dots, P_k \}$ of polynomial expressions.  For instance the expression $(x + y)(x-y) \not\equiv (x^2 - y^2)$ although their polynomials are the same.  Each $P_i$ is a polynomial expression for a polynomial in $F[x_1, \dots, x_k]$.  So it's the coefficients of the polynomials that make up the "code".  The ***time complexity*** $T$ of an algorithm on an $F^k$-machine is defined to be the total operations needed to compute the polynomial expressions as they are given so $(x+y)^k$ would be $T = 1 + \ln(k)$.

**Def 2.** A ***deterministic problem*** is two sets $X, Y$ together with a map $f : X \to Y$.

**Def 3.** A problem is ***compatible with an $F^k$-machine*** if there exists algorithms on a standard machine for *encoding* and *decoding* respectively the input and then ouput.  That is, $X \xrightarrow{\phi} F^k \xrightarrow{\psi} Y$.

- $\phi, \psi$ must be computable in $O(|x|)$ time where $|x|$ is the size of input $x \in X$.  For instance if $X \subset \Bbb{Z}$, $|x| \approx \log_p(x)$.
- There must exist a function $f^* : F^k \to $ itself such that $f = \psi f^* \phi$.

**Theorem 1.** For any $F^k$-compatible problem $f$, there exists a set of polynomials $\{f^*_1, \dots, f^*_k\} \subset F[x_1, \dots, x_k]$, such that $f(x) = \psi \circ (f^*_1, \dots, f^*_k) \circ \phi(x), \ \forall x \in X$,  and an algorithm for computing them in time $O(p^k k^2 ln(p))$.
**Proof**: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756714/any-problem-computable-in-k-memory-slots-can-be-computed-with-polynomials).

**Lemma 1.** A problem $f: X \to Y$ is computable in time $O(t(|x|)) \iff$ there exists a sequence $X_0 \subset X_1 \subset X_2 \dots = X$ such that for each $X_i, \ f_{X_i} : X_i \to Y$ is a problem computable in time $O(t_i(|x|))$ and each $t_i(|x|)$ is $O(t(|x|))$. **Proof:** $\Rightarrow$, obvious, take $X_0 = X$.  $\Leftarrow$, given any specification $|x| \leq K$, for some $K \in \Bbb{R}$, there is a smallest set $X_i$ such that $x \in X_i, \ \forall |x| \leq K$, and a problem $f_{X_i} \to Y$ that's solvable in $O(t(|x|))$ time.  That says that the problem is computable in $O(t(|x|))$ time, by usual standards.

---

Let's define a C-like language.  We've already shown that an $F^k$-machine can compute any deterministic problem for which it is compatible.  We want to show that the run times of algorithms run on a standard machine using the $C$-like language are similar to some algorithm on a $F^k$ machine that computes the same problem.

Let the language be a sequence of statements each of which can be a while-loop or a conditional, an assignment (=) or arithmetic operation (+,*), and each of those can contain a sequence of statements (recursively).  You can also declare variables and static arrays.  All loops are of the form "while(x < y)" and all conditionals are "if(x < y)".  Convince yourselve that this is a powerful enough language and also there's a transformation of algorithms written in it to a standard machine language that preserves the time and space complexity.

Intuitively, it seems like this is a standard computer language and can compute anything a turing machine can given enough memory.  More importantly it can compute anything that a standard home computer archictecture can.  And vice versa, given enough memory for code and data.  Iow, I'm not proving that here.

**Conjecture 1.** For any deterministic algorithm on the "C-like machine" with $F$-sized words, whose problem is compatible with an $F^k$-machine there is a time and space complexity-preserving transformation of the algorithm to an $F^k$-machine algorithm.  **Proof** Since our problem is $F^k$ compatible, there already is a set of computing polynomial expressions by Theorem 1, but we want to show that there are polynomials expressions whose time and space complexity equals that of the C code algorithm.   Since the algorithm is deterministic, we can precompute the values taken on by all loop-referenced variables in time and space proportional to the original, so that each while loop can be transformed into:

```
 for(i=N; i > 0; i--) {
     // reference all i-dependent data here
 }
```

where N is a constant that depends on input $x^* \in R^k$.  So set it to $\max_{x^*} \{N(x^*)\}$.  Let all i-dependent data that's not part of our input $x^* = $ x[1..k] be pre-computed.  For an algorithm that runs in $O(t(|x|))$ time we will need $C t(|x_m|)$, where $x_m \in X$, memory slots, maximum, to precompute the i-dependent data.  Clearly that bound is correct.   Now suppose that our algo is now composed of recursive for-loops like above and assigments to our input variables held in $x[1..k]$.  A typical example would be:

```
for(i=N; i > 0; i--) {
    for(j=M; j > 0; j--) {
        x[0] += a[0] + x[i]*b[j] + 2;
        x[1] *= x[0] + x[j]*c[i] - 3;
    }
        x[i] = x[i-2] * x[i - 10] + 100;
}
```

Let's convert conditional statements into those of the form "x[i] (*= | += | = ) Arithmetic".  Each conditional assignment

```
if(a < b)
   x = c
```

can be written $x := x p_1(a,b) + c (1-p_1(a,b))$ where $p_1(a,b) = \sum_{(u,v) \in F^2} p_2(u,v)(1 - (u - a)^{p-1})(1-(v-b)^{p-1})$ where $p_2(u,v)$ are the coefficients of $p_1$, and $p_1$ answers the question *is $a \lt b$*.  $p_1$ is calculable on a standard machine in $O(1)$ time so each conditional assignment can be rewritten to a polynomial expression that can be evaluated in $O(c) = O(1)$ time on a standard machine.

Thus now our code looks like the recursive tree of for-loops and assignment /arithmetic statements to x[1..k], and the only cost to complexity is an increase in programm memory (constants that make up the i-dependent data + regular constants + instructions), that is proportional to the running time or $O(t(|x|)^3)$ but usually a lot less.  Except this is not the true picture, I just realized.  There may be loops inside of conditionals and conditionals inside of loops, and so on, but each assign / arithmetic operation may be taken out of the conditional.

Starting at the inner most loops, say of varying degere N, we have our first sequence of code that's only a sequence of $n$ assigns / arithmetic ops.  Traverse the operations sequentually and each time you come across x[j] = E, do $P_j := E$ on our $F^k$ side.  If you cross x[j] *= E do $P_j := P_j * E$, and so on... Then you've built up the $P_j$'s for that innermost loop. Now destroy the loop and write x[j] = $P_j$ for each affected variable from the killed loop.  Now you should have assigns / ops in a conditional or in another loop.  Keep killing inner-most loops until you can completely collapse the code structure into a set of assignments $x[j] = P_j$.  Notice that the computational complexity of the resulting $P_j$ is exactly the same as that of the C code if it were interpreted directly, without any optimization.

I think that's the gist of what we're trying to prove and how to prove it.

*What are your thoughts on this work?*

Comment: How would you transform something like: `double x = 1; double x_next = .5 * x + 1.0/x; while(abs(x_next - x) > 0.01) {x = x_next; x_next = .5 * x + 1.0 / x;}` (btw, this would be Newton's method for computing $\sqrt{2}$).  I'm guessing the answer is assume it terminates (if it doesn't it's out of the scope of the problem) and therefore this loop should loop $N$ times and the `x`'s and `x_next`'s will take on $N$ (possibly) different values.